# How to deal with a small concrete patch in hardwood floor install

Tags: concrete, flooring, hardwood

I am installing 3/4 inch oak throughout my first floor. The install is over the original pine, which sits directly on the joists. I put 1/4 OSB over the pine (due to a number of factors 5/8" wasn't practical).

I removed a tile hearth pad where there used to be a fireplace. That left me with a roughly 2 ft x 5 ft concrete patch that I had to deal with. I placed 1/4 hardiebacker concrete board to get it roughly even with the floor and then patching compound to level it out. There is also 1/4 OSB over the patch area, which I secured with concrete screws. The long side of the patch runs perpendicular to the floor boards against a wall.

What is the least-bad way of securing the hardwood over that patch? I'm a relative newbie to this, so any insights are very much appreciated!

Comment: How are you securing the oak to the osb in the other areas? Why is this area to be different?

Comment: I am planning on using 2 inch cleats with a flooring nailer. This will be different, I assume, because the cleats won't be able to penetrate the combo of 3/4" flooring + 1/4" OSB + 1/4" cement board + whatever depth of actual cement is underneath.

Comment: So do a test before you start then you will know what to do - perhaps use 1.5" ...